# Missing aggregate components

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

The `durchfuehrungen` are in a few cases `null` even if the records are correct and the cogrouping with them works elsewhere.
In the history of the resulting affected `ProjektAggregat` records no single event contains the depending `durchfuehrungen`, they’re always null and couldn’t figure it out why.

```scala
Function { projekte: KStream<String, ProjektEvent> ->
            Function { projektstatus: KStream<String, ProjektStatusEvent> ->
                Function { befunde: KStream<String, ProjektBefundAggregat> ->
                    Function { aufgaben: KStream<String, ProjektAufgabeAggregat> ->
                        Function { wirtschaftseinheiten: KTable<String, WirtschaftseinheitAggregat> ->
                            Function { durchfuehrungen: KStream<String, ProjektDurchfuehrungAggregat> ->
                                Function { gruppen: KStream<String, ProjektGruppeAggregat> ->
                                    Function { mietobjekte: KTable<String, MietobjektAggregat> ->
                                        projekte
                                            .leftJoin(wirtschaftseinheiten)
                                            .leftJoin(mietobjekte)
                                            .cogroup { _, base, current: ProjektAggregat ->
                                                current.copy(
                                                    projekt = base.projekt,
                                                    wirtschaftseinheit = base.wirtschaftseinheit,
                                                    mietobjekt = base.mietobjekt,
                                                    projektErstelltAm = base.projektErstelltAm
                                                )
                                            }
                                            .cogroup(projektstatus.groupByKey()) { _, projektstatusEvent, aggregat -> aggregat + projektstatusEvent }
                                            .cogroup(befunde.groupByKey()) { _, befundAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + befundAggregat }
                                            .cogroup(aufgaben.groupByKey()) { _, aufgabeAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + aufgabeAggregat }
                                            .cogroup(durchfuehrungen.groupByKey()) { _, durchfuehrungAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + durchfuehrungAggregat }
                                            .cogroup(gruppen.groupByKey()) { _, gruppeAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + gruppeAggregat }
                                            .aggregate({ ProjektAggregat() }, Materialized.`as`(projektStoreSupplier))
                                            .toStream()
                                            .filterNot { _, projektAggregat -> projektAggregat.projekt == null }
                                            .transform({ EventTypeHeaderTransformer() })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Event if I change the stream to use `leftJoins` instead of `cogrouops` there are missing `durchfuehrungen`:

```scala
    Function { projektstatus: KStream<String, ProjektStatusEvent> ->
                Function { befunde: KStream<String, ProjektBefundAggregat> ->
                    Function { aufgaben: KStream<String, ProjektAufgabeAggregat> ->
                        Function { wirtschaftseinheiten: GlobalKTable<String, WirtschaftseinheitAggregat> ->
                            Function { durchfuehrungen: KStream<String, ProjektDurchfuehrungAggregat> ->
                                Function { gruppen: KStream<String, ProjektGruppeAggregat> ->
                                    Function { mietobjekte: GlobalKTable<String, MietobjektAggregat> ->
                                        projekte
                                            .filterNot { _, projektEvent -> projektEvent.action == CREATE_REQUEST }
                                            .leftJoin(wirtschaftseinheiten)
                                            .leftJoin(mietobjekte)
                                            .leftJoin(projektstatus.toTable()) { aggregat, projektstatusEvent ->
                                                projektstatusEvent?.let { aggregat + projektstatusEvent } ?: aggregat
                                            }
                                            .leftJoin(befunde.toTable()) { aggregat, befundAggregat -> befundAggregat?.let { aggregat + befundAggregat } ?: aggregat }
                                            .leftJoin(aufgaben.toTable()) { aggregat, aufgabeAggregat -> aufgabeAggregat?.let { aggregat + aufgabeAggregat } ?: aggregat }
                                            .leftJoin(durchfuehrungen.toTable()) { aggregat, durchfuehrungAggregat ->
                                                durchfuehrungAggregat?.let { aggregat + durchfuehrungAggregat } ?: aggregat
                                            }
                                            .leftJoin(
                                                gruppen.toTable(),
                                                { aggregat, gruppeAggregat -> gruppeAggregat?.let { aggregat + gruppeAggregat } ?: aggregat },
                                                Materialized.`as`(ProjektStore.NAME)
                                            )
                                            .toStream()
                                            .filterNot { _, projektAggregat -> projektAggregat.projekt == null }
                                            .process(ProcessorSupplier { EventTypeHeaderProcessor() })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is a bug in the event type filtering mechanism of Spring Cloud Stream which causes several matching records to not to arrive at the stream. After deactivating the feature all desired records arrive.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2627